# Get a dynamic ID from am input field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the  `id` of an `input field` which has a dynamic id but I get an error unrecognized expression. Below is my code :

```
  $("#amount_paid' + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id + '").keyup(function() {
       var amount_owed = $('#amount_owed' + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id + '').val();
       var amount_paid = $('#amount_paid' + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id + '').val();
       alert('Amount owed' + amount_owed + 'Amount paid' + amount_paid + '');
       if (amount_owed < amount_paid) {
           alert('Amount to be paid exceeds amount owed');
       }
   });
```

What is the best way to get the value from the  id amount_paid which has dynamic id for each entry ?

Comment: `$("#amount_paid" + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id )` - use string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate

```
$("#amount_paid" + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id).keyup(function () {
       var amount_paid =  this.value;
       var amount_owed = $("#" + this.id.replace("amount_paid", "amount_owed")).val();
}):
```

Comment: Did you check my code ,it is worked for you, or any error coming

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
$("#amount_paid" + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id )
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Thanks.