# Jquery Get a dynamic class name from a dynamic field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the  following script which is generated on a click of a button :

```
 $('.pharmacy_service_payments').on('click', '.pharmacy_service_payment_link', function() {

   //get
   var visit_id = $(this).closest('li').find('input[name="visit_id_list"]').val();

   var patient_id = $(this).closest('li').find('input[name="patient_id_list"]').val();

   html1 = '';
   htmlhead1 = '';
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>cashier/pharmacy_service_payments_details/" + visit_id + "/" + patient_id,
     dataType: "JSON",
     success: function(data) {
       for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

         html1 += '<div>\n\
                    <div class = "form-group">\n\
        \n\
                    <textarea required=""  class = "form-control" style="width:100px" readonly="" name="description[]" id = "description"  >' + data[i].description + '</textarea>\n\
        </div>\n\
        <div class = "form-group">\n\
        \n\
        <input type = "text" required="" class = "form-control" style="width:80px" readonly="" name="amount_charged[]" id = "amount_charged" value="' + data[i].amount_charged + '" placeholder = "Amount Charged">\n\
        </div>\n\
        <div class = "form-group">\n\
        \n\
        <input type = "text" required="" class = "form-control" name="amount_owed[]" readonly="" style="width:80px" id = "amount_owed" value="' + data[i].amount_owed + '" placeholder = "Amount Paid">\n\
        </div>\n\
        <div class = "form-group">\n\
        \n\
        <input type = "text" required="" class = "form-control amount_paid' + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id + '" name="amount_paid[]"  style="width:80px" id = "amount_paid' + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id + '"  placeholder = "Amount Paid">\n\
        </div>\n\
         <div class = "form-group">\n\
        \n\
        <input type = "text" required="" class = "form-control" style="width:80px" readonly="" name="quantity[]" id = "quantity" value="' + data[i].quantity + '" placeholder = "Quantity">\n\
        <input type="hidden" required="" readonly="" name="patient_visit_statement_id[]" id="patient_visit_statement_id" value="' + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id + '">\n\
        <input type="hidden" required="" readonly="" name="patient_id[]" id="patient_id" value="' + data[i].patient_id + '">\n\
        <input type="hidden" required="" readonly="" name="visit_id[]" id="visit_id" value="' + data[i].visit_id + '">\n\
        <input type="hidden" required="" readonly="" name="patient_payment_id[]" id="patient_payment_id" value="' + data[i].patient_payment_id + '">\n\
        <input type="hidden" required="" readonly="" name="payment_prescription_tracker[]" id="payment_prescription_tracker" value="' + data[i].prescription_tracker + '">\n\<input type="hidden" required="" readonly="" name="amount_paid_td[]" id="amount_paid_td" value="' + data[i].amount_paid + '">\n\
        \n\
        \n\
        </div>\n\
        <div class = "form-group">\n\
        \n\
        \n\
        <select required="" name="payment_method[]" class="" id="payment_method">\n\
        <option value="' + data[i].payment_method + '">' + data[i].payment_method + '<option>\n\
        <option value="Cash">Cash</option>\n\
        <option value="M-Pesa">M-Pesa</option>\n\
        <option value="Airtel Money">Airtel Money</option>\n\
        <option value="Orange Money">Orange Money</option>\n\
        <option value="PDQ">PDQ </option></select>\n\
        </div>\n\
        <div class = "form-group">\n\
        \n\
        <textarea type = "text" style="width:80px" required="" class = "form-control" name="payment_code[]" id = "payment_code" value="' + data[i].payment_code + '" placeholder = "Payment Code">' + data[i].payment_code + '</textarea>\n\
        </div>\n\
                    </div>';

         //Check if the  amount paid is greater than the  amount owed. 

         $("amount_paid" + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id).keyup(function() {
           alert('Amount found');
           var amount_paid = this.value;
           var amount_owed = $("#" + this.id.replace("amount_paid", "amount_owed")).val();
         });
       }

       htmlhead1 += '<div>\n\
                    <div class = "form-group">\n\
        <label class = "label label-info" for = "description">Description</label>\n\
        </div>\n\
        <div class = "form-group">\n\
         <label class = "label label-info" for = "amount_charged">Amount Charged</label>\n\
        </div>\n\
        \n\
        <div class = "form-group">\n\
        <label class = "label label-info" for = "balance_remaining">Balance Remaining</label>\n\
        </div>\n\
        <div class = "form-group">\n\
        <label class = "label label-info" for = "amount_paid">Amount Paid</label>\n\
        </div>\n\
         <div class = "form-group">\n\
        <label class = "label label-info" for = "quantity">Quantity</label>\n\
        </div>\n\
        <div class = "form-group">\n\
        <label class = "label label-info" for = "payment_method">Payment Method </label>\n\
        </div>\n\
        <div class = "form-group">\n\
        <label class = "label label-info" for = "payment_code">Payment Code </label>\n\
        </div>\n\
                    </div>';
       $('#patient_pharmacy_service_payment_div').empty();
       $('#patient_pharmacy_service_payment_div').append(htmlhead1);
       $('#patient_pharmacy_service_payment_div').append(html1);
     },
     error: function(data) {}
   });

 });
```

Inside the  script I have included a keyup function which is supposed to check if the amount paid / keyed in is greater than the  amount owed and it returns a value. 
But when I run the script , there no response from the  on click of the key up . I tried using the  following : [Get a dynamic ID from am input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641364/get-a-dynamic-id-from-am-input-field) approach but it still failed, Please advise...

Comment: That is a lot of code you have added. I suggest you organize it and only show what is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding the keyup event to an element that has not been added to the DOM yet.

(your selector is also missing the '#'...)

Either place your binding code underneath the part where you add the generated HTML to the DOM, or create a delegated event handler:

```
$("#patient_pharmacy_service_payment_div").on("keyup", "#amount_paid" + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id, function () {
    // fancy stuff...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The key up event which you have added helps only if the DOM element is present at the time of page load. 
For dynamic DOM elements you should use the **on** event. Make sure you are using a Jquery version greater than 1.7.2.
Your key up code must be

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#amount_paid" + data[i].patient_visit_statement_id, function () {
                    alert('Amount found');
                    var amount_paid = this.value;
                    var amount_owed = $("#" + this.id.replace("amount_paid", "amount_owed")).val();
                });
```